# How to create a compliment popup text after 4 to 5 taps or moves in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-4.0

I want to create a scenario in which I kill (Tap) 3 enemies in game and a compliment word like "excellent", or "Good Job" pops out.

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: sorry about the caps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.